# can a 2x4 withstand 200lbs out pressure on the 1.5" side?

Tags: deck, handrail

I need to know if I cut a 2x4 at 42", which will be down the side of a 2x8 by 7 inches, carriage bolted at 2" and 5" below the surface of the deck, bolted through a 2x8 (1.5" thick), that will extend 34.5" above the surface of the deck, if it will withstand 200lbs of outward pressure at the top (which is handrail height).

The 2x4 will be flat (3.5" side) against the 2x8 girder.

```
  ||
  ||
  ||
  ||_________________________
  ||------------------------- decking  
 *||| BOLT
  |||
 *||| BOLT
  |||_________________________ 2x8 Girder
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you are located, but if you are in the US, this is typically a question for the engineer signing off on your deck plans in the permitting process.

Comment: You are looking at a torque not a force. If the railing is 3 feet for example you would care about the 2x4 withstanding 600lbft. Where did you get the 200lbs number? Is this for a railing? Are there multiple supports or just one?

Comment: TOP RAIL MUST SUPPORT 50 LBS./FT. BOTH VERTICALLY AND HORIZONTALLY SIMULTANEOUSLY OR 200 lbs CONCENTRATED LOAD ANYWHERE ALONG THE LENGTH -[Page 43](http://www.cityofchicago.org/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf)

Comment: The ASCII art is confusing, can you draw a diagram, or create a model in CAD software? Also explaining exactly what you're trying to do, might help folks come up with alternative solutions, or at least understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR -If the question is if you can use a 2x4 for a post, then the answer is no.

For guardrails see here, [page 42 -6A](http://www.cityofchicago.org/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf) (Chicago Deck Code).

Whatever a 2x4 can withstand is irrelevant. Guardrail posts are to be at minimum 4x4s.

The top rail is to be a 2x6 with a 'cap'.

Maximum span for a railing between two posts is 4'.

Use at minimum 5/8ths through bolts with 2" - 3/16ths washers to secure the post to the ledger board (and unless you want to do it again in five years, buy all stainless fasteners).